# Propagation of uncertainties in functions not continuously differentiable

Tags: uncertainty, error-propagation

According to the [*Guide to the Expression of Uncertainty in Measurement*](http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/guides/) as published by the *Bureau International des Poids et Mesures (BIPM)*, the combined standard uncertainty $u_c^2$ for a function $y = f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_N)$ where all input quantities are independent (uncorrelated) is given by
$$
u_c^2(y) = \sum_{i=1}^N \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\right)^2 u^2(x_i) \, ,
$$
where $u(x_i)$ is the standard uncertainty for input quantity $x_i$.

This only works if $f$ is continuously differentiable.  Is there an analytic way to estimate the propagation of uncertainties if this is not the case?  For example, in remote sensing, we might consider a function classifying a surface as dry land, liquid water, or snow/ice.

We can of course estimate the propagation of random errors by simulation or repeating the measurement many times (if feasible), but if possible, an analytic calculation may be desirable.

Comment: You don't need normality of errors for simulation, you just need to understand their distribution well enough to simulate it. And considering that there are just so many different flavors of non-differentiability ($f$ could be continuous, or not, one-sided derivatives could exist or not and go off to infinity or simply have different limits, ...), I don't really think you can do any better than either simulating or including specific knowledge about your specific $f$.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Good point, I edited the last paragraph (you need to understand a lot of processes well enough to simulate it...).  A specific example I'm thinking of is classification, which means $f$ takes on a finite number of discrete values, but the question is more generic.